# Need help on clarification of input dialog of matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have the following code:

```
%%input dialog box%%%
prompt = {'Enter gain:','Enter range:'};
dlg_title = 'Enter values';
num_lines= 1;
def     = {'20','256'};       %default
answer  = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);

%%%to get the two entered values%%%%
A = getfield(answer,{1});    %first input field
A = str2double(A);
B = getfield(answer,{2});   %second input field
B = str2double(B);
```

What does it mean to use "dynamic field names with structures instead of `getfield`"?

How can I use a loop for the input values that are complex and smaller than zero, in the sense to request the user for another compatible input?

I've tried the following loop but it does not work. Why?

```
while isnan(A) || ~isreal(A) || A<0
    prompt = {'Enter gain:'%'Enter range:'};
    dlg_title = {'undefine!!'};
    num_lines= 1;
    def     = {'',''}%{'20','256'};       %default
    answer  = inputdlg(prompt, dlg_title, num_lines, def);
    A = getfield(answer,{1});    %first input field
    A = str2double(A);
    %A = str2double(input('Enter the value of module(mm) : ', 's'));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The calls to `getfield` aren't required and frankly don't make any sense.  The variable `answer` is a `cell` array not a `struct` so you don't need to use `getfield`  The second half of the pasted code could be replaced with:

```
A = str2double( answer{1} );
B = str2dobule( answer{2} );
```

With regards to looping until you get valid input. You can use a `boolean` flag, a `while`, loop and a `function` (lets call it `areInputsValid()`) that returns true if the inputs are valid

```
validInput = false;

while (~validInput)
  % input dialog box
  %  code here

  % get the two entered values
  &  code here

  validInput = areInputsValid(A, B);
end
```

Comment: I'm not very clear with the looping could you provide a more concrete example? thank you so much @slayton